# detect if color is between two colors with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I want detect if each pixel of an image is in a range between two colors. I get the pixel color with **getImageData** but now I don´t know how know if it is in the range.
any idea?
thanks

Comment: What's your definition of a color being "in a range" between two colors?

Comment: yes, but I don´t know how do the same with blue tones, for example.
if I put:
var cmin = {r:0, g:0, b:255};
var cmax = {r:0, g:0, b:50};

don`t work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HSL colors, the H means Hue (what we normally think of as the color).  If you use HSL colors, you can do as Stano suggests and just calculate the linear distance between any pixel hue and your specified hue(s).

```
HueDesired – HuePixel
```

But computer images are normally defined in the RGB color model.  **RGB uses a blend of colors** to make your desired color.  With RGB you can determine if 2 colors are “close” by calculating their Euclidian distance from each other on the color wheel.

Here’s a function to calculate the Euclidian distance between a specified color and a pixel color:

```
// find Euclidian distance from the pixel color to the specified color 
//
function colorDistance(colorRed,colorGreen,colorBlue,pixelRed,pixelGreen,pixelBlue){

    var diffR,diffG,diffB;

    // distance to color
    diffR=( colorRed - pixelRed );
    diffG=( colorGreen - pixelGreen );
    diffB=( colorBlue - pixelBlue );
    return(Math.sqrt(diffR*diffR + diffG*diffG + diffB*diffB));

}
```

Since you want to compare the pixel to 2 colors, just run this function for both of your 2 colors.

It’s up to you to determine what is an “acceptable” distance between your 2 colors and the pixel color, but this function will give you a measuring tool to work with.

Comment: thaks, you are the boss! this is what I needed.

Comment: underrated answer!